# Bash sed muti word find and replace

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am getting the error "unterminated substitute pattern" on mac os when attempting to replace multiple words with a different set of multiple words separated by spaces. I am doing this in a bash script. Reading from csv to replace a set of strings in files.

example

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3

#$col1=FOO BAR
#$col2=another set of words
#$col3=file

do
   REGX="'s|$col2|$col3|g'"
   sed -i -e $REGX $col1
done < $config_file
```

I want the output to be "another set of words" can't seem to find out how to allow the spaces in the expression.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some real example? Current syntax is fine, but you probably have some slashes or weird characters that break the `sed` command.

Comment: I have updated to what I am really doing as I think it is something to do with it being run via bash.

Comment: I have managed to get it working by using eval "sed -i -e $REGX $col1" but kind of hopping there is a batter way. I think bash was not adding '' around the statement.

Comment: What's the point of storing the regex apart? I would just do `sed -i -e "s|$col2|$col3|g" col3`.

Comment: Yeah that works, was just doing that so I could echo it to help see what was going wrong, how ironic cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the substitution to do in a variable so that you use later on:

```
REGX="'s|$col2|$col3|g'"
sed -i -e REGX col3
```

Another example:

```
$ cat a
hello this is a test
$ REGX="s/this/that/g"
$ sed $REGX a
hello that is a test
```

However, I would directly use the command as follows:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3
do
   sed -i.bak -e "s|$col2|$col3|g" $col1
done < $config_file
```

Notes:

- Use `-r` in `read` to avoid weird situations on corner cases.
- Use double quotes in `sed` so that the variables within the expression are evaluated. Otherwise, it will look for literal `$col2` and change with literal `$col3`.
- Use `-i.bak` to create backup files when using `-i`. Otherwise, if you try and fail... you will lose your original document.

Comment: Sorry typeo in the question I only missed out the $ in the question. Your solution is correct but not for that error. I have updated the question.

Comment: True enough, @StuartCampbell . I deleted that reference from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s#foo bar#another set of words#g"
# OR
sed -i "s#foo|bar#another string#g"
```

sed use `|` as regex `OR`, use another separator (the default `/` suite well here also)

Comment: This is not true. Have you tried it? `sed -i "s|foo bar|another set of words|g" file` works perfectly.

Comment: cannot test on my AIX but the sed is on MAC and this is not a pure GNU sed nor shell. On standard GNU, you are right, by default not using extend regex. Message is tell 'unterminated ...' so sed cannot find delimiters

Comment: ... which doesn't have anything to do with what you answered :)

Comment: i just use other separator to avoid the ambiguous `|` in this case but the request does not specify if it is a `OR` (with wrong understanding of s///) or a separator (badly interpreted by sed)? I guess the first, so my second proposition of the post.

Comment: Although I think the OP knows about the basic `sed 's/search/change/g' file` format and it has to do with the "foo bar" being looked for, you definitely have your point. Let's see if the OP updates with more info.